# sort specific array element value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array...

```
Array
(
    [banana] => 1
    [orange] => 2
    [mango] => 1
)
```

What I need is How do i get the exact string value to view on the following table. example the banana value to the add to 1. banana table column value.

The table below is HTML View table, Not Mysql table.

```
 type      value
-------------------
1.mango  |    
2.banana |
3.orange |
------------------
```

in short how do i search the array to get the value of each and insert value to table below.

Comment: Use basic `update` query. If you don;t know it's syntax - follow any mysql manual on the web.

Comment: the table is not mysql, it is simple html table to view

Comment: Iterate over array with `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: please do it fully, I have tried with that one but not working...

Comment: the expected output is the table you see on the above

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a foreach.

```
<?php
$array = array("banana" => 1, "orange" => 2, "mango" => 1);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $val){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Output :

[image: output]

---

The same format as your question would be :

```
<?php
$array = array("banana" => 1, "orange" => 2, "mango" => 1);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $i++;
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "$i.$key"; ?></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Output :

[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

Internet,

combine *foreach* and *switch*.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Use a foreach to loop through your array and then insert this in your database.

```
foreach( $fruits as $fruit -> $value{

       ...passing data to your database insert function 
   ...i.e. $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO kunden (type, value) VALUES ('".$fruit."', '".$value."')");

}
```